# Ternary operator using print function

Tags: python, printing, conditional-operator

```
print( (b, a) [a < b] ) 
print((lambda: b, lambda: a)[a < b]())
```

How does this function work? 
**What is happening behind the cover?** 
What is the difference between these two?
**(PYTHON)**

Comment: Please ask a single question. And try making that question the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(b, a)` is a tuple, which can be indexed just like a list -- `(b, a)[0]` evaluates to `b`, `(b, a)[1]` to `a`. The trick here is that in Python, bools also act like integers -- `False` like 0 and `True` like 1. `a < b` evaluates to a bool -- to `True` if `a` is less than `b`, to `False` otherwise.

FWIW Python has had a real ternary operator for a while now -- the normal way to write something like this would be `a if a < b else b`. Although actually in this particular case, you'd probably go for the even shorter `min(a, b)`!